# Ошибка IDE PyCharm 2022.1.1

Tags: python, pycharm

При выполнении кода:

```
a = str(input())
if a == 'tr':
    b = int(input())
    print(type(b))
```

на первом шаге `a = str(input())` ввожу буквы **tr**
на втором шаге `b = int(input())` ввожу целое число **5** и на выходе получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\caspa\OneDrive\Desktop\1.py", line 3, in <module>
    b = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

на сколько я понимаю ошибка говорит о том, что я ввожу пустое значение, хотя я ввожу **число!**
[image: Дополнительно скриншот кода и ошибки]

Comment: Глюки пишармовской "консоли". Причем в дебаге такой проблемы нет. Можно им в багтрекер написать, а самому жить с настройкой "Run with python console"

Comment: @vitidev, не посоветуете еще что-нибудь тут или по ссылке ниже, а то участник с низкой (пока) репутацией спросить не может? Вот его вопрос: <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1412852/%d0%92%d1%80%d1%83%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b6%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83?noredirect=1#comment2513688_1412852>