# Вручную ввожу символы и выдает ошибку

Tags: python

У меня такая ошибка при вводе вруную

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programs\pythonProject\lesson.py", line 2, in <module>
    B = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Хотя такой ошибки раньше не было.
Вот например:

```
A = int(input())
B = int(input())
H = int(input())
if A <= H <= B:
    print("Это нормально")
elif H > B:
    print("Пересып")
else:
    print("Недосып")
```

Если я введу второй символ то сразу выдает ошибку, и это не только в этом коде ошибка, даже когда складываю два числа через **int(input())**, ввожу первое число, и на втором ошибка, я заметил если я буду вводить данные через **ctrl v + ctrl c**, всё нормально работает. Помогите, как исправить ошибку?

Comment: У вас Enter дважды вводится. Либо клавиатура, либо баг tool. Уже были тут жалобы на это. Вот, например, <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1411374/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-ide-pycharm-2022-1-1>

Comment: Я так и не понял что мне делать

Comment: 1) клавиатуру проверили? 
2) написано же в комментарии по приведённой ссылке - выполнили? 3) Если 1 и 2 не помогает - проведите поиск по StackOverflow по теме "invalid literal for int() with base" и почитайте все рекомендации и ответы, последовательно  выполняя.

Comment: Извините за глупый вопрос, а как enter проверить если вводиться дважды, и что такое баг tool ?

Comment: 1) В редакторе попечатайте что-то, да повводите Enter. Будет вводится дважды - он сломан.
2) В самой среде запуска какие-то сбои, скорее всего.  По ссылке, что я дал, есть совет как обойти в PyCharm. У вас - PyСharm, или какая среда?

Comment: С enter нормально, да Pycharm, по ссылке перешел  но не понимаю что значит написать им  в багтрекер

Comment: В python console, все нормально работает

Comment: Спрашивайте тогда в том вопросе тогда, кто посоветовал. Но там же был способ, как запуститься.

Comment: Репутации не хватает, я даже переустанавливал pycharm, и настройки сбрасывал, не помогло

Comment: я просто уже не знаю как исправить эту проблему

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136519/discussion-between--and-kazak).

Comment: Нужно просто [подождать](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54238/STDIN-is-lost-for-a-second-input-call). А пока что в `Run | Edit Configurations` использовать  "Emulate terminal in output console" или "Run with python console"